# Solr delete by id is working, but delete by query isn't

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 4.0 beta. I found that I am able to delete a document by id but I can't do the same work using delete by query, for example `noticeId:728`, and I can use the same query syntax to select what I want. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You need to show us more.  Show us how you're doing the delete by query.  Show us how you're doing the delete by ID.  If we can't see code, we can't help you.  Edit the question to include these things.  Don't add them as comments below.

Answer (score 2):

Time to move up from beta, maybe you have just hit out the bug [Delete by Query bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3432)

Comment: Agree, Solr is at version 4.3 currently, would recommend you upgrade to a released version, even if this is your issue.